מִזְבֵּחַ marked with פשטא and accentuated מלרע?
It is my understanding that the absolute noun מִזְבֵּחַ is never marked with just one פשטא (and accentuated מלרע) but always שני פשטין (and accentuated מלעיל), the latter in accordance with its proper stress on the penultimate syllable. For example:
בראשית 12:8
שמות 28:43, 29:37, 30:20, 38:4
ויקרא 1:5, 1:16, 9:7, 16:12
במדבר 4:26, 17:11, 18:3, 18:17
However, I recently came across a fascinating Yemenite חומש in תאג׳ תורה קדומה and all 13 cases have it marked with one פשטא and accentuated מלרע. The "חלק הדקדוק" there to שמות 29:37 (see a more detailed commentary here and especially here) explains as follows:

לז. והיה המזבח֙. בפשטא אחת והיא מלרע, בכל ספרי תימן, והיא שיטת מהרי״ץ בכל מקום. ובתאג י״ם לא עמדו על דעת רבינו בזה ועשאוה בתרין פשטין היפך דעתו והיפך התיגאן, ופשוט. שוב מצאתי גילוי גדול לדעת רבינו במוסרת תאג קדמון בפרשת ויקהל על פס׳ ויעש למזבח מכבר דמסיר עלה ׳למזבח, כלהון ביתיב חד׳ הרי זה בניין אב לכל המקרא שלעולם לא תבוא תיבת המזבח בתרין פשטין אלא בפשט אחד. ומעתה אָבַד סִבְרוֹ וּבָטַל סֵיכוּיוֹ של כל הבא לחלוק על דברי מוסרה זו שקבעוה קמאי דקמאי עפ״י חכמי המוסרה. יפ״ה׃

Do any non-Yemenite commentators/grammarians address the possibility of מִזְבֵּחַ shifting from מלעיל to מלרע and having פשטא to reflect that syntax? (The second link, ד״ה כמובן, notes that the מנחת שי is silent on this matter.)

Is a patach genuva counted as a syllable such that it can take a ta’am? Do we ever see a patach genuvah with an unambiguous trop sign on it?

@JoelK When they say a word like מזבח is מלרע it means they pronounce it without a   פתח גנובה. Apparently (according to the last paragraphs of this) the ancient Yemenite tradition was to never pronounce a פתח גנובה, while the ancient Tiberian tradition which the Yemenites adopted was to pronounce it in some instances (not like our current tradition to pronounce it everywhere)

@ba I don't think that's how R Ratzabi understands Maharitz. At the very end he writes לפעמים יש באותה הפרשה, פעם 'מזבח' מלעיל, ופעם 'מזבח' מלרע, וכן בתיבת 'ניחוח', פעם כך ופעם כך ... לפי קריאת הקדמונים, יכול להיות שהם קראו נִיחֹוח, ואז לא היתה שאלה אם זה מלעיל או מלרע. אבל מהרי"ץ מדבר לפי קריאת בן אשר, ובקריאת בן אשר ישנן ראיות שיש חילוק בין אם יש פשטא אחת, או תרין פשטין.

@JoelK He says the קדמונים (what I called the "ancient Yemenite tradition") would probably have pronounced it נִיחֹוח (i.e. without פתח גנובה) in all instances, but according to קריאת בן אשר (what I called "the ancient Tiberian tradition which the Yemenites adopted," and which is being transmitted by the Maharitz) the פתח גנובה is pronounced in some instances (which were marked with תרין פשטין for מלעיל) but not in others (which were marked with a single פשטא for מלרע and no פתח גנובה)

@ba To me that seems to be very unlikely to be what he Maharitz is saying to do. You would have the word ניחוח marked in the Taj with a patah under the het, but would know to pronounce it as if were written without a patah under the het, solely because there is a single pashta instead of double pashta? Why not just drop the patah under the het?

@JoelK I don't know. Maybe because (some of) those words are pronounced with פתח גנובה in other instances. Maybe it shouldn't be written when unpronounced. The double pashta is used as a proof because it's an effect, although not the cause, of the פתח גנובה being counted as a syllable (following the two-vowel rule linked in the question). What actually determines if the פתח גנובה is pronounced isn't clear to me, but it seems pretty clear to me that in that article when he says מלרע it's supposed to mean without פתח גנובה.

But Encyclopedia of Hebrew language and linguistics III, 1017 ("Yemen, pronunciation traditions") seems to read the Maharitz like you, and says that a minority of Yemenites read this way (image)

@ba Thanks for the link. Just to clarify, I’m not at all certain that Maharitz actually meant to put the stress on the het, but I do think that’s how R Ratzabi in the linked pieces is reading him.
